# Is there an email send limit for Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email, email-studio

my company has Salesforce Sales Cloud installed, which has a current limit of 5000 List Emails per day.
We're evaluating to install the Marketing Cloud too, but we want to know if there is a similar limit for it, and how much it is.
Does anyone know?
Thank you,
GC

Answer (score 2):

Marketing Cloud is a completely separate app, you don't "install" it.

In Marketing Cloud, there is a concept of super messages - based on your contract, you buy a number of super messages which are then used for "paying" for sending emails. If you're out of super messages, you can always buy more, so technically there are no limits.

> A quantity of Super Message types is included in each Basic, Pro,
> Corporate and Enterprise Edition and additional Super Messages can be
> purchased at any time during a subscription term. Entitlements for
> each category can be applied to one or more messaging channels and
> each messaging channel consumes one or more entitlements. The details
> of messaging channels and applicable multipliers are outlined below:
>
> Email Messages
>
> 1 Email consumes 1 Super Message
>
> 1 High Priority Triggered Email consumes 4 Super Messages
>
> 1 Interactive Email consumes 1 Super Message

Source: https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/Agreements/product-specific-terms/marketing-cloud-super-message-bundles.pdf

Comment: @Gianmarco if this answer helped you, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark - thanks!